# create X.xaml and X.xaml.cs files vs should understand they are xaml and code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i create two files `NodeControl.xaml` and `NodeControl.xaml.cs`,

in the xaml file wrote  `x:Class="TreeTest.NodeControl.NodeControl"`

in the cs file i wrote partial and in the constructor i call `InitializeComponent();`

thay are worked fine but VS2010 didn't understand they are xaml and code behind

[image]

did i do something wrong?

Comment: I suggest not naming sub-namespace and class name with same name because then you cannot use NodeControl from code (for example in MainWindow.xaml.cs) without fully qualifying it with namespace (using TreeTest.NodeControl; won't work).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because Visual Studio doesn't know they are associated. It's just a naming convention to have .xaml and .xaml.cs. IN the project file you need to enforce the relationship via:

```
<Compile Include="NodeControl.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>NodeControl.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```